# Google-checkout notification callbacks

Tags: google-checkout

I have problem with Notification API callbacks. I've implemented callbacks in Sandbox account without problems, but when I switched into production no notification arrived and Integration console is empty. I set up SSL url...

Thanks for help.

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

When "switching" to production, did you:

- check if you are using your **production** merchant id and key?
- check if you have adjusted the [urls where you POST data to](http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Google_Checkout_Cart_Post_Troubleshooting.html) (urls are also different for sandbox and production)?

Comment: Production account is different from sandbox. I'm just waiting for notification callbacks from Google Notofication service. I set up integration link into integration section. Thanks.